# How to convert volts to dB SPL

Tags: pic, sound, decibel

I am taking input from an electret microphone amplified using LM358 amplifier from my PIC16F877A's ADC unit. I am getting the readings in volts from the ADC which ranges from 2.5V to 5V.

How can I convert these readings into dB?

Comment: Use the sensitivity figure given in the microphone's datasheet.

Comment: Here is the datasheet of the mic:- http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Sound/CEM-C9745JAD462P2.54R.pdf

Comment: It's sensitivity is -46±2.0,(0dB=1V/Pa) at 1K Hz.

Comment: The LM358 has too much noise (hisssss) and other problems to be a mic preamp. Use an audio opamp instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

dB SPL is a [pressure measuring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure) unit.

You can't convert a voltage to a dB SPL reading unless you know:

- the [microphone sensitivity](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/46-05/understanding_microphone_sensitivity.html) (or simply the analog output voltage to the input pressure ratio) which tells you essentially the voltage level it will output for a given sound pressure level
- the gain that the preamp has applied

---

Your microphone has a sensitivity of -46dBV/Pa , this gives 0.005012 V RMS/ Pa
1 Pa (pascal) equals 94 dB sound pressure (SPL)

The dB equation for voltage is \$ 20 \times \log  \frac {V_1}{V_o} \$
where \$ V_1 \$ is the voltage being measured, and \$ V_0 \$ is the reference level.

If we do an example calculation for the measurement of 2.5 V (assuming a unity gain for the amplifier) we get

\$ 20 \times \log  \frac {2.5}{0.005012} = 53.96 \ \text{dB} \$

so the SPL will be (-46) + 53.96 = 7.95 + 94 = 101.95 dB SPL

We assumed a unity gain for the preamplifier; if the actual gain was 20dB then the SPL becomes:
101.95 - 20 = 81.95 dB SPL

If the actual gain was 10dB then the SPL becomes:
101.95 - 10 = 91.95 dB SPL
...

Comment: I knew the mic's sensitivity: It's sensitivity is -46±2.0,(0dB=1V/Pa) at 1K Hz

But nothing about gain that the preamp has applied

Comment: I suppose you could calibrate the preamp, or even use its ideal equations as a very close estimate.

Comment: @alexan_e: Thank you very much. Just one more help in detemining the gain of my OpAmp.

Comment: @user35456 You said you are using a LM358 preamp so the gain is set with the resistor values you have used and should be definable. For example, if it looks like [this](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Audio/lf071_mic.htm) then the gain is set by R2,R1. Also check if you have applied any gain in your ADC (I'm not familiar with PIC ADC)

Comment: I also have a very similar situation. I'm using [Electret Mic with Max4466 amplifier](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1063). My mic's sensitivity is -44dB @1kHz but I don't know what the Op-Amp gain is. The amplified output is 1.5V to 3V where the supply voltage is 3V. According to the datasheet, the gain can be adjusted from 25x to 125x.

Comment: @alexan_e : Sorry to drop here so late. But could you explain why you are doing (-46) + 53.96 + 94 to get the Db SPL. It seems to me that you are manipulating numbers with different units here.

Comment: @alexan_e : I mean if you have 0.005012 V RMS / Pa. It means that you have 0.007088 V / Pa. So if you measure 2.5V, it is equivalent to 353 Pa. And so the dB SPL should be 20 * log10(353/0.000020) = 145 dB

Comment: Bit late to party, but... when in the example you measure 2.5V, that's RMS? I guess it has to be RMS because the reference level is in RMS, but the talking about an ADC that's most likely 2.5Vpp. Just trying to understand...

Answer (score 3):

Coming here many years later and I am still confused by the top answer, only because I am trying to solve this exact problem.

As stated in the top answer, voltage gain is calculated as 20*log10(V1/Vref)
where V1 is the Vrms of the measured voltage and Vref is the microphone sensitivity. Then, the microphone sensitive in dB is subtracted off (-46dBV/Pa) before being added to dB SPL standard (94 dB SPL), but this doesn't quite make sense to me.

If you put a standardized tone generator outputting 94 dB SPL at 1 kHz, you would expect (and I have experimentally validated) to get exactly the value of the microphone sensitivity (in your case, 0.005012).

Plugging this into the top answers formula, you would get
20*log10(.005012/.005012) = 0 dB - 46 (db rel V/Pa; microphone sensitivity) + 94 db = 48 dB, when it should be 94 dB, because we are using a standardized tone generator.

I believe the correct conversion would just be
20*log10(V1/Vref) + 94 dB SPL, where V1 is the rms voltage of the signal and Vref is the microphone sensitivity.

Comment: +1, I think you are correct. Adding -46 dB is unnecessary, cz it is already accounted for while voltage gain is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

-46dB V/Pa is how I read it and 1 Pa is the sound pressure in newtons per sq metre. 0dB SPL is 20 micro Pascal therefore, 1 Pa is 50,000 times bigger or, in dB it is 94 dB SPL.

So, if you are measuring -46 dBV then you are measuring a SPL of 94 dB. -46 dBV is near enough 5 mV RMS so, again, if you measure 5mV RMS then the SPL is 94dB.

If you have a pre-amplifier with a gain of ten, then 50mV RMS equates to 94dB SPL and 5mV would equate to a SPL of 74 dB.

This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: So, how to convert the volts I'm getting in the RMS?? Just divide it by sqrt(2)?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are measuring from your ADC. If it were me I'd be sampling at 50kHz and calculating RMS by squaring each sample, averaging and then taking the sqrt of the average. I have no idea how your code works or what it does.